# How to implement "notification" for receiving messages from a conversation partner

Tags: python, django, websocket, signals, django-channels

I have implemented a simple messenger. How can I implement a "notification" system for receiving messages from a conversation partner? For example, when User 2 sends a message to User 1, User 1 should see a notification icon indicating an unread message, all without page reload. I believe this can be done using signals, websockets, and Django Channels, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

i tried using signals and websocket

Comment: The way to go is indeed using Django Channels for WebSockets. You would also need a bit of Javascript to connect to the websocket and show an alert. Your question is too broad to answer, I'd advice to go over some tutorials for using WebSockets in Django.  This should familiarize you with consumers and channels.